# How to enroll for salesforce developer certification exam

Tags: certification

i am living in Pune and want to apply for developer certification.
Can anyone please help me how to do it and the cost?

Answer (score 1):

- [Visit this link](http://certification.salesforce.com/)
- On Top Right Corner you will find link as REGISTER FOR EXAM.
- Sign Up on the www.webassessor.com page and register for exam.
- The exam fee for any certification is available under Credentials tab.

Comment: Please do not ask for the OP to mark as accepted in the answer as that is not accepted in our community standards here.

Comment: Edited the answer. Acknowledged!

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow below steps to register for a Salesforce Certification Exam

**Registering for an Exam**

Follow the below steps to register for a salesforce.com certification exam.  You can also check exam availability by following these registration steps.

- Log in to [Webassessor](http://www.webassessor.com/salesforce). If you do
  not already have a test taker profile in Webassessor, you will need
  to create one.
- Click Register for an Exam.
- Locate the exam you wish to schedule and expand the section to view
  the delivery options. You can choose to register for the exam as
  onsite proctored or online proctored. Click the Register button for
  the delivery method you prefer.
- If you are interested in online proctored exams, please review all
  system requirements at
  http://certification.force.com/pkb/articles/Public_KB/Online-Proctoring-Completing-Your-Exam-Remotely.
- If you selected the onsite proctored exam: Select a testing center.
- Select the date and time you would like to take the exam; read the
  Reschedule and Cancellation Policy, select the acknowledgement
  checkbox.
- If you selected the online proctored exam: Select the date and time
  you would like to take the exam; read the Reschedule and Cancellation
  Policy, select the acknowledgement checkbox.
- All online proctored exams are automatically adjusted to the time
  zone of the location you inputted in your Webassessor profile
  details.
- Click Select.
- Review the exam and scheduling details for accuracy, click Checkout.
  Enter your payment type. You can enter a voucher/coupon code and/or
  credit card.
- Click Submit.
- You will see a purchase confirmation screen. Click Done.
- An email confirming your purchase and registration will be sent to
  you.

[Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000186542&language=en_US)